# The relationship between decision variables in objective function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, differential

I have an objective function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ in an optimization problem, and don't know if all these variables are independent or not. Therefore, I want to know if $\dfrac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_3}$, or the partial derivative of $x_2$ with respect to $x_3$ is greater, less than, or equal to zero. Is total differentiation the right approach?

Or is $\dfrac{\partial x_2}{\partial  x_3}$ equal to $\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_3^2}}{\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2x_3}}$, and if so, why does this hold?

Comment: If the variables are not independent, then you need to express that as constraints. This will potentially reduce the dimensionality of your objective function as well.

Comment: The problem is I don't the constraints about $x_2$ and $x_3$, but I do know if the term on the numerator and denominator is positive or negative, howver I don't if that equality holds or not.

Comment: You know $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_2}$ so that implies $x_1 = f(x_2)$ right?

Comment: For the last comment, I meant I know the signs of $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_3^2}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2x_3}$, so if the formula I mentioned in the post hold, I can find the sign of $\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_3}$, however I don't if it holds or not.

And sorry I don't really understand your point in the last comment.

Comment: I don't think you have enough info to solve this then. Presumably, your objective function should only be in terms of independent variables.

Comment: Thank you. But it's given that they are not independent. I guess the first sub-question of this is what the right formula for finding $\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial x_3}$.

Comment: Ok- so you want to know if you can infer $\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_2}$ using only the partial derivatives of $f$?

Comment: Exactly, and I only want to know if it's positive or negative, not exact result.